# Phase of signal can affect the data rate?

Tags: phase

Does the change of phase of the signal affect the data rate?

Actually, I consider the RIS(Reconfigurable Intelligent Surfaces) between the transceiver and receiver. I wonder if adjusting the phase shift matrix of RIS can improve the datatate.

Comment: uff, you're mixing a very basic question ("does phase affect the data rate") with a very advanced concept (RIS). Yes, RIS can increase the data rate. That's why they have been invented. However, considering your current line of questions, I'll be very honest: you'll do best first getting a good understanding on classical communications technology before trying to understand RIS – there's a lot of statistics, information theory and signal theory that you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Reconfigurable Intelligent Surfaces can change phase of the incoming signal. If the channel parameters can be obtained perfectly at RIS then
a communication system with RIS improves data rate in general. The received signal at the user without RIS can be defined as,

$$
y =  hs+n
$$

where the $s$ is transmitted signal, $h$ is channel fading coefficient and $n$ is the noise. In the system model which consists RIS, received signal at the user can be given as,

$$
y = \sum_{x \in \chi} h_xg_xs+n
$$

where the $x$ is unit RIS element and $g_x$ represent phase change at unit RIS element $x$. As can be seen from the equations above, RIS can increase the signal-to-noise ratio via counteracting against channel fading.